# R: Lookup table / combine two dataframes

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have two dataframes `df.old` and `df.new`. Now, I'd like to add the PID-variable from the `df.old` dataframe to the new dataframe, where the e-mail-adress matches. Where no mail-adress is available, the matching should be done using first name and last name (`paste(firstname, lastname)`). How can this be done efficiently?

My first guess was to create two "lookup"-functions `get_PID_by_mail(mail)` and `get_PID_by_name(firstname, lastname)`, vectorize them and apply them in `df.new %>% mutate(PID=get_PID_by_mail(mail))`. But this turned out to be a little inefficient as the dataframes are large. How would you solve this? THanks!

```
df.old <- data.frame(PID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA),
                     firstname = c("", "Peter", "David", "Jessy", ""),
                     lastname = c("", "White", "Smith", "Connor", ""),
                     mail = c("user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", NA, "user10@mail.com", NA))

df.new <- data.frame(mail = c("user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", NA, NA , NA),
                     firstname = c("", "", "", "David", ""),
                     lastname = c("", "", "", "Smith", ""))
df.new
```

Expected output:

```
df.new
======
   mail                firstname lastname  PID
1  user1@mail.com                          1
2  user2@mail.com                          2
3  <NA>                                    <NA>
4  <NA>                David     Smith     3
5  <NA>                                    <NA>
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I added the expected output

Comment: @D.Studer, it's possible I am missing something but would `left_join(df.old,  df.new)` not accomplish this?

Comment: @RKeithL I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minute after the other answer, but doing it with `bind_rows`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df.old <- data.frame(PID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA),
                     firstname = c("", "Peter", "David", "Jessy", ""),
                     lastname = c("", "White", "Smith", "Connor", ""),
                     mail = c("user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", NA, "user10@mail.com", NA))

df.new <- data.frame(mail = c("user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", NA, NA , NA),
                     firstname = c("", "", "", "David", ""),
                     lastname = c("", "", "", "Smith", ""))

bind_rows(
  df.new |>
    filter(mail != "") |>
    left_join(df.old |> select(mail, PID)),
  
  df.new |>
    filter(is.na(mail)) |>
    left_join(
      df.old |> filter(is.na(mail)) |> select(firstname, lastname, PID),
      by = join_by(firstname, lastname)
    )
)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(mail)`
#>             mail firstname lastname PID
#> 1 user1@mail.com                      1
#> 2 user2@mail.com                      2
#> 3           <NA>                     NA
#> 4           <NA>     David    Smith   3
#> 5           <NA>                     NA
```

### Edit - skipping bad emails

Simplest way to do a more robust check on emails would be to use a regex for testing email validity for the first match, and negating it (and detecting NAs) in the second, then joining the results:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df.old <- data.frame(PID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                     firstname = c("", "Peter", "David", "Jessy", "Bad", "Gordon"),
                     lastname = c("", "White", "Smith", "Connor", "Email", "Bennet"),
                     mail = c("user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", NA, "user10@mail.com", NA, "oldemail@mail.com"))

df.new <- data.frame(mail = c("user1@mail.com", "user2@mail.com", NA, "" , "bademail@none", "newemail@mail.com"),
                     firstname = c("", "", "", "David", "Bad", "Gordon"),
                     lastname = c("", "", "", "Smith", "Email", "Bennet"))

# Step 1: all valid, present, emails with matching records:
first_join <- df.new |>
  filter(str_detect(
    mail,
    "^\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*$"
  )) |>
  inner_join(df.old |> select(mail, PID), by = join_by(mail))

# Step 2: all remaining records, with invalid emails, missing emails or
# non-matched emails; join to first set
df.new |>
  anti_join(first_join, by = join_by(mail)) |>
  left_join(df.old |> 
              anti_join(first_join, by = join_by(mail)) |> 
              select(firstname, lastname, PID),
            by = join_by(firstname, lastname)) |> 
  bind_rows(first_join, second = _)
#>                mail firstname lastname PID
#> 1    user1@mail.com                      1
#> 2    user2@mail.com                      2
#> 3              <NA>                     NA
#> 4                       David    Smith   3
#> 5     bademail@none       Bad    Email   5
#> 6 newemail@mail.com    Gordon   Bennet   6
```

Mr Bad Email here cannot be matched by email (as it's not a valid email address) so it's skipped and he's matched by name. Mr Gordon Bennet has changed his email, so his new one isn't found and he's matched by name. Finally, David has an empty string as email (`""`), so he's skipped and matched by name. The invisible person with no name, email or PID is kept in the new dataframe as specified.

Comment: May I just ask for one adaptation? As far as I understand your code, the name is only checked if there is no email available `filter(is.na(mail))`. However, it could also happen, that the e-mail is not valid for some reason (type error etc.). In that case the name should be used EVEN THOUGH an e-mail is available. I hope you understand, what I mean. Actually it should not check EITHER the mail OR the name, but FIRST the mail and if this fails ALSO the name.

Comment: I've added a more robust style of checking if you want to take a look at that and see if it works? essentially the two join statements should be non-overlapping - one with valid emails and one with all non-valid emails - then these are bound after the matching steps. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Andy for your effort. If I understand your code right you check whether the e-mail adress is valid or if there is no e-mail at all. However, it can also happen that there is a formally valid e-mail adress that still doesn't appear in the `df.old` dataframe because the adress might have changed over time. So in that case (if there is no matching using the e-mail adress) the name should also be checked 

Comment: I've put in an edit to the second block of code which should catch no-email-matches and match by name. A couple of `anti_join`s will try the rematch on precisely the rows of `df.old` and `df.new` not resolved in the first match done by all valid emails. 

Answer (score 2):

Using two `left_join`s you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df.new |>
  left_join(df.old |>
    filter(!is.na(mail)) |>
    select(PID, mail), by = "mail") |>
  left_join(df.old |>
    filter(is.na(mail)) |>
    select(-mail), by = c("firstname", "lastname")) |>
  mutate(PID = coalesce(PID.x, PID.y), .keep = "unused")
#>             mail firstname lastname PID
#> 1 user1@mail.com                      1
#> 2 user2@mail.com                      2
#> 3           <NA>                     NA
#> 4           <NA>     David    Smith   3
#> 5           <NA>                     NA
```